# media image is not able to display on webpage

Tags: django, django-templates

when click on "yo" I am able to see media file but when tried to display image through the image tag it is not seen on webpage

```
<a href="{{status.adv.url }}">yo</a>
<img src="{{status.adv.url}}" width="250" height="250"  alt="advertise"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<img src="{{status.adv.url}}" width="250" height="250"  alt="advertise"/>
```

to

```
<img src="{% static status.adv.url %}" width="250" height="250"  alt="advertise"/>
```

and include `{% load static %}` template tag on the top of your template(s)

Your project url.py should have these

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Documentation: [Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css)

Comment: image is uploaded on website and stored inside media folder not static

Comment: yeah, that doesn't matter, media can be served with a static template tag, Share your media files settings and project url.py

Comment: @JAYESHrathi see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It was add blocker used by me. so disable your add blocker.

If you want to confirm that it is add blocker open your chrome and in console you will find this "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"